# jOOQ: returning list with join,groupby and count in single object

Tags: java, jooq

***Core question: how do you properly fetch information from a query into objects?***

**Idea**
I am creating functions in my DAO, which comes down to the following query:

```
select A.*, count(*)
from A
left join B on B.aId = A.aId
group by A.*
```

Im looking for a way to create a jOOQ expression that just gives me a list (or something I can loop over) with objects A (pojo) and Integer.

**Concrete case**
In my code case: A = Volunteer and B = VolunteerMatch where I store several matches for each volunteer. B has (volunteerId, volunteerMatchId) as primary 
key. Thus this query results in both the information from the Volunteer, as well as the number of matches. Clearly this can be done in two seperate queries, but I want to do it as one!

**Problem**
I cannot find a single object to return in my function. I am trying to get something like List<VolunteerPojo, Integer>. Let me explain this better using examples and why they dont fit for me.

**What I tried 1**

```
SelectHavingStep<Record> query = using(configuration())
        .select(Volunteer.VOLUNTEER.fields())
        .select(Volunteermatch.VOLUNTEERMATCH.VOLUNTEERID.count())
        .from(Volunteer.VOLUNTEER)
        .leftJoin(Volunteermatch.VOLUNTEERMATCH).on(Volunteermatch.VOLUNTEERMATCH.VOLUNTEERID.eq(Volunteer.VOLUNTEER.VOLUNTEERID))
        .groupBy(Volunteer.VOLUNTEER.fields());

Map<VolunteerPojo, List<Integer>> map = query.fetchGroups(
                r -> r.into(Volunteer.VOLUNTEER).into(VolunteerPojo.class),
                r -> r.into(Volunteermatch.VOLUNTEERMATCH.VOLUNTEERID.count()).into(Integer.class)
        );
```

The problem with this, is that I create a List from the integers. But that is not what I want, I want a single integer (the count will always return one row). Note: I don't want the solution "just create your own map without list", since my gut says there is a solution inside jOOQ. Im here to learn!

**What I tried 2**

```
SelectHavingStep<Record> query = using(configuration())
        .select(Volunteer.VOLUNTEER.fields())
        .select(Volunteermatch.VOLUNTEERMATCH.VOLUNTEERID.count())
        .from(Volunteer.VOLUNTEER)
        .leftJoin(Volunteermatch.VOLUNTEERMATCH).on(Volunteermatch.VOLUNTEERMATCH.VOLUNTEERID.eq(Volunteer.VOLUNTEER.VOLUNTEERID))
        .groupBy(Volunteer.VOLUNTEER.fields());

Result<Record> result = query.fetch();
for (Record r : result) {
    VolunteerPojo volunteerPojo = r.into(Volunteer.VOLUNTEER).into(VolunteerPojo.class);
    Integer count = r.into(Volunteermatch.VOLUNTEERMATCH.VOLUNTEERID.count()).into(Integer.class);
}
```

However, I do not want to return the result object in my code. On each place I call this function, I am calling the r.into(...).into(...). During compile time, this won't give an error if it returns an integer or a real pojo. I don't want this to prevent future errors. But at least it doesn't give it in a List I suppose.

**Reasoning**
Either option is probably fine, but I have the feeling there is something better that I missed in the documentation. Maybe I can adapt (1) to not get a list of integers. Maybe I can change Result<Record> into something like Result<VolunteerPojo, Integer> to indicate what objects really are returned. A solution for each problem would be nice, since I am using jOOQ more and more and this would be a good learning experience!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So close! Don't use [`ResultQuery.fetchGroups()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/ResultQuery.html#fetchGroups-org.jooq.Table-org.jooq.RecordMapper-). Use [`ResultQuery.fetchMap()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/ResultQuery.html#fetchMap-java.lang.Class-org.jooq.RecordMapper-) instead:

```java
Map<VolunteerPojo, Integer> map =
using(configuration())
    .select(VOLUNTEER.fields())
    .select(VOLUNTEERMATCH.VOLUNTEERID.count())
    .from(VOLUNTEER)
    .leftJoin(VOLUNTEERMATCH)
    .on(VOLUNTEERMATCH.VOLUNTEERID.eq(VOLUNTEER.VOLUNTEERID))
    .groupBy(VOLUNTEER.fields())
    .fetchMap(
         r -> r.into(VOLUNTEER).into(VolunteerPojo.class),
         r -> r.get(VOLUNTEERMATCH.VOLUNTEERID.count())
    );
```

Comment: Oh cool! Extra question: what if I used another join and I got three objects? How do you do it then?

Comment: @Rico: I'm happy to answer a new question for that (with an example of what "three objects" means)