# jOOQ: returning list of three objects from joins

Tags: java, jooq

This question is an extension of [jOOQ: returning list with join,groupby and count in single object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49678222/jooq-returning-list-with-join-groupby-and-count-in-single-object), but now with three objects instead of two.

**Idea**

```
select A.*, B.*, C.*
from A
left join B on B.aId = A.aId
left join C on C.bId = B.bId
```

**Concrete example**

```
SelectWhereStep<Record> query = using(configuration())
        .select(Student.STUDENT.fields())
        .select(Volunteermatch.VOLUNTEERMATCH.fields())
        .select(Volunteer.VOLUNTEER.fields())
        .from(Student.STUDENT)
        .leftJoin(Volunteermatch.VOLUNTEERMATCH).on(Volunteermatch.VOLUNTEERMATCH.STUDENTID.eq(Student.STUDENT.STUDENTID))
        .leftJoin(Volunteer.VOLUNTEER).on(Volunteer.VOLUNTEER.VOLUNTEERID.eq(Volunteermatch.VOLUNTEERMATCH.VOLUNTEERID));
```

How do i fetch the results from the query?

Comment: It isn't query! It is only step of Select. This data you can use for next query or you can it fetch to an object. It may by list of JOOQ models or list of your objects.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a `fetch()` call at the end of your query.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have something like a "Triple" class available to you (below I use the [Apache Commons](https://commons.apache.org/) class), and assuming you just want the first result:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple.Triple;

Record r = query.fetchAny();
return Triple.of(r.into(VOLUNTEER), r.into(VOLUNTEERMATCH), r.into(STUDENT));
```

If you want multiple results, then probably something like:

```
query.fetchStream().map(r-> Triple.of(
  r.into(VOLUNTEER), r.into(VOLUNTEERMATCH), r.into(STUDENT) )
).collect(toList());
```